# SQL insert to MySQL doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, insert

I'm currently trying to insert username, pw to a DB, and check if the username already exists.

The problem is that the SQL (select) syntax doesn't work, nor does the (insert). I've checked around for a couple of hours in forums and Stackoverflow, and my current code is the following.

What might be the problem?

Thanks, Jimmie.

```
 <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "name";
    $password = "pw";
    $dbname = "dbaname";

    $mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ((isset ($_POST["identity"])) && (isset ($_POST["pin"])) && (isset ($_POST["token"])))
    {

      $identity = htmlspecialchars($_POST['identity'], ENT_QUOTES, "ISO-8859-1");
      $pin = htmlspecialchars($_POST['pin'], ENT_QUOTES, "ISO-8859-1");
      $token = htmlspecialchars($_POST['token'], ENT_QUOTES, "ISO-8859-1");

      echo "$identity";
      if($token == "xyz13D;A##:!#")
      {


        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `identity` FROM Users WHERE `identity` = '" . $identity . "'");
        if($result->num_rows == 0)
        {
           echo "successCreat";

              // Perform queries
              mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM Users");

              mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO Users (identity,pin,userActivity, identityCreated) VALUES ('$identity', '$pin',1,now())");
        }
        else
        {
          echo "failureCreate";
        }

      }
      else
      {
        echo"Wrong Key";
      }
    }
    $mysqli->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake. `htmlspecialchars`  is **NOT** a proper escaping method.

Comment: If identity is a primary/unique key, then mysql should either throw an exception or set an error flag if a duplicate entry is added.

Comment: What response do you get, `successCreat`, `failureCreate`, `Wrong Key`, other?

Comment: I did error checking, but it didn't show anything. Apparently, as what I've checked this 'should' be safe enough, but I will of course check your links.I do get "successCreat", since the Select query doesn't work.

Comment: As for Tadman's comment.

Here's a code snippet for the (select) syntax. Do you think this is a better approach?

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `identity` FROM `Users` WHERE `identity` LIKE '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['identity']) . "';");

Comment: Also, I think a few of the users comments is not for any help. If you have a suggestion of change, you're free to comment. Otherwise, don't waste any time.

Comment: I can see one problem in your first select query, the mixing of ` and ', usually using ` brings problems in my queries. Or you can try echoing the query and then copy and run the echoed query directly in phpMyAdmin panel to see what output it gives

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `identity` is a primary key, then you can check the error flags after executing an INSERT query to see if an error occurred.

```
mysqli_query( $mysqli, "INSERT INTO ... " ); //< ... Represents query
if (mysqli_error( $mysqli )) {
  echo "Failure";
}
else {
  echo "Success";
}
```

Also, you should properly escape input as stated in the comments. In addition, you should check whether or not the connection attempt was successful using `mysqli_connect_error`.

Finally, there might be an issue in your SQL suntax which `mysqli_error` will also catch. A last possibility is that the POST data isn't being set properly and the code is being ignored completely.

Comment: Okay, well I did get the Success, which is good.

Also I echo the identity to see if the is a value, which there is. Also I get connection..

Thank you!